# как остановить функцию в python (telebot)

Tags: python, telebot

мне нужно остановить функцию так как нужно перейти на следующую функцию под названием math

вот код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):  
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Привет!как ты?')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def porduce(message):
    if message.text=='плохо':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'не расстраивайся')
    elif message.text=='хорошо':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'вот и отлично')
    else:
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'ну и такое бывает')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['math'])
def math():
    x=int(input("Введите первое: "))
    y=int(input("Введите второе: "))
    operation=input(" ")
    if operation=='+':
        print (x + y)
    elif operation=='-':
         print (x - y)
    elif operation=='*':
         print (x * y)
    elif operation=='/':
         print (x / y)
    else:
        print("введите правильный символ")
```

Comment: `input` выполняется на сервере, где будет бот запущен, вы уверены, что именно так задумываете работать с ботом? :D

Comment: я не знаю но мне нужно чтобы первое и второе числа были в переменных

Answer (score 1):

если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['math'])
def math(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите два числа\n_прим. 2 5_', parse_mode='Markdown')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, math_introductory)


def math_introductory(message):
    try:
        if len(message.text.split()) > 1:
            introductory = message.text.split()
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите операнд\n_прим. +, -, /, *_', parse_mode='Markdown')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, math_operation, introductory)
        else:
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверный ввод, повторите')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, math_introductory)
    except Exception as error_input:
        print(error_input)


def math_operation(message, introductory):
    a = int(introductory[0])
    b = int(introductory[1])
    if message.text == '+':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '{}'.format(a + b))

    elif message.text == '-':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '{}'.format(a - b))

    elif message.text == '/':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '{}'.format(a / b))

    elif message.text == '*':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '{}'.format(a * b))
    
    else:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверный ввод, повторите')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, math_operation, introductory)
```

Вы можете оптимизировать данный код, запрашивая операнд сразу с числами.
Так же не забудьте добавить проверку на `isdigit()`.